# Changing a rectangle's X value does not actually move it in the GUI

Tags: python, qgraphicsview, pyside2

I'm working on a GUI in Python with PySide2. I have a GraphicsView, where I'll put an image, and I'd like to draw and move a polygon around on that image. I've found many examples of simply drawing polygons, circles, etc. in PySide, PySide2, or PyQt 4/5 in Python. However, I haven't been able to figure out why my graphics items do not move on an event without deleting and redrawing.

I'm using the keyboard to change the X value on a PySide2 `QRectF`. The `X` value is clearly changing, but the rectangle does not actually move.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from functools import partial

class DebuggingDrawing(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # initialize the scene and set the size
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._scene.setSceneRect(0,0,500,500)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        # make a green pen and draw a 10 wide, 20 high rectangle at x=20, y=30
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 0)
        self.draw_rect = QtCore.QRectF(20, 30, 10, 20)
        # add the rectangle to our scene
        self._scene.addRect(self.draw_rect, self.pen)

    def move_rect(self, dx: int):
        # method for moving the existing rectangle
        # get the x value
        x = self.draw_rect.x()
        print('x: {} dx: {}'.format(x, dx))
        # use the moveLeft method of QRectF to change the rectangle's left side x value
        self.draw_rect.moveLeft(x + dx)
        self.update()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.labelImg = DebuggingDrawing()

        # Get a keyboard shortcut and hook it up to the move_rect method
        next_shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence('Right'), self)
        next_shortcut.activated.connect(partial(self.labelImg.move_rect, 1))

        # get the left key shortcut, move_rect one pixel left
        back_shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence('Left'), self)
        back_shortcut.activated.connect(partial(self.labelImg.move_rect, -1))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.labelImg)

        self.setMaximumHeight(480)
        self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    testing = MainWindow()
    testing.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

You clearly can't see in the image, but even though the rectangle's `x` value is changing according to our print calls, nothing moves around in the image. I've confirmed it's not just my eyes, because if I draw new rectangles in `move_rect`, they clearly show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`draw_rect` is a `QRectF` is an input to create an item([`QGraphicsRectItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsrectitem.html)) that is returned by the [`addRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addRect) method similar to `pen`, that is, it takes the information but then no longer uses it. The idea is to move the item using `setPos()`:

```
class DebuggingDrawing(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # initialize the scene and set the size
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        # make a green pen and draw a 10 wide, 20 high rectangle at x=20, y=30
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 0)
        draw_rect = QtCore.QRectF(20, 30, 10, 20)
        # add the rectangle to our scene
        self.item_rect = self._scene.addRect(draw_rect, pen)

    def move_rect(self, dx: int):
        p = self.item_rect.pos()
        p += QtCore.QPointF(dx, 0)
        self.item_rect.setPos(p)
```

If you still want to use draw_rect then you have to set it again in the item:

```
    self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 0)
    self.draw_rect = QtCore.QRectF(20, 30, 10, 20)
    # add the rectangle to our scene
    self.item_rect = self._scene.addRect(self.draw_rect, self.pen)

def move_rect(self, dx: int):
    # method for moving the existing rectangle
    # get the x value
    x = self.draw_rect.x()
    print('x: {} dx: {}'.format(x, dx))
    # use the moveLeft method of QRectF to change the rectangle's left side x value
    self.draw_rect.moveLeft(x + dx)
    self.item_rect.setRect(self.draw_rect)
```

It is recommended that ["Graphics View Framework"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) be read so that the QGraphicsItems, QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene work.